# Align UIViews to left

Tags: objective-c

I want align UIView's to left, like the property align="left" in html or float:left with css, it's possible in objective C?

Note: the UIViews are dynamically loaded.

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I have an unknown numbers to view and I want to stack them align:left just like HTML (as you have mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate them, set the frame to something suitable. Also set autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin.

Comment: Hum, an example would be great :D, sorry i'm novice